# ESD damage without earth ground

Tags: ground, esd, earth, floating

Can you explain how a totally floating PCBA (with semiconductor chips/ components stuffed, but no any connection to earth GND) is damaged by an ESD event from human touch?

If human body is charged to a high voltage with regards to earth and it picks up this unpowered and floating PCBA, will the charge transfer from finger to a node on the PCBA and create a large potential difference between this node and some other node nearby, creating a local current flow inside the PCBA, without any need for current to return to the earth GND?

Does this assumption make sense? If not, what’s the actual mechanism taking place?

Comment: You're assuming you need actual metal connections to have a complete circuit and therefore conduct current.  You don't.  The item in question is capacitively coupled to the environment.   The current flow is through this "capacitor".   An ESD event is very high voltage but generally very very low current.   So even a very small capacitance is adequate to allow the vanishingly small current to flow (long enough to cause damage at least).   If you're unfamiliar, google "displacement current" for a description of how current can flow through the space between plates of a capacitor.

Comment: If you charge a balloon with static electricity, you can feel it lifting your hair centimeters away. If you are charged and wave your hand centimeters above a PCB it will redistribute charges on PCB. There might be kilovolts of potential difference between you and the PCB.

Comment: @KyleB: The current is often several Amps, I would not qualify this as "very very low current".  This is the reasone for possible component damange. Only the time the curent flows is very short.

Comment: @Jens fair enough....I meant 'total current' and could have been clearer with that.   But we only get like 500 characters in a post. ;)  Yes it can be quite high for a few nanoseconds.    The point I was making is the very small stray capacitance is large enough to allow damaging current to flow.

Answer (score 1):

The entire device can be approximated as an equipotential surface, like a metal sphere.

Say, you stand on an insulating surface, and charge yourself from a VanDeGraaf generator to a MV or a few, then the generator connection is removed. Then someone on the ground throws a suitably sized spherical metal shell to you. You'll feel the charging current as the sphere approaches your hands. Basically, you'll feel a little "zap" as the shell takes some of your charge away. Throwing such a metal sphere back and forth would be a way to drain your charge away so that you won't die/get hurt by stepping off the insulator and discharging all at once.

Every little "zap" will flow through the sphere, or through your little circuit, even if everything is isolated, you as well :)

PS. I've been the person standing on the ground. It was fair: both me and the other student standing on the insulator would get zapped an equal number of times :) It took a *long* time before we could not feel the "zaps" anymore and deemed the situation to be safe.

Comment: The device is a capacitor, but only one lead, i.e. not a two-terminal circuit element.   Static electricity, moving charge, doesn't correspond to 'circuit' topology, but charge flows nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Turn it around:

How does a totally floating human damage an earthed circuit by ESD event, if there is still no ground path?

Would a totally floating (and similarly charged) circuit be damaged by touch from an earthed human?

Simple: the ground return path is by capacitance through space / surroundings.  So your assumption is correct: current flows through the contact, until the object's charge is equalized with the body (or vice versa).  No earth needed.  And so, the answer to the two above questions are also "yes".

Voltage is purely differential, it needs no absolute reference (indeed the notion of an absolute reference is somewhat meaningless) -- we merely use ground as a convenience, an arbitrary definition.  With no shortage of confusion when we neglect to communicate what we mean by ground in some given context (as I'm more than guilty of doing myself..).

If you draw the equivalent circuit, the two bodies' capacitances (to space) act in series (for the double-floating case) -- which reduces to whatever that series combination is.  (There's also the capacitance between them directly, since, you're bringing them into proximity to be able to discharge them together, of course; but we can lump that into the equivalent, too.)  So the effect is less ESD to a smaller (but isolated) object, than to a small but grounded (in the AC / RF sense*) object.

Indeed, there is also a standard for such interactions: when an electrical component becomes charged, then gets placed on a circuit board, or work table, or handled, etc., its own charge (quite small for most board-level electrical components) is discharged through quite low resistance -- potentially metal-on-metal contact.  This CDM (Charged Device Model) event is much more potent per volt, but much lower voltages are usually encountered this way (<500V?), too.

*Hmm, I probably shouldn't add that, because that's simply making a big composite object.  The messy part comes in realizing that ESD is a very fast event, some nanoseconds -- so the propagation of waves really does apply, even over/through the human body, and especially along circuitous earth wires (which may have negligibly high impedances at these rates!).  Hence the stipulation that it be well-grounded at AC, which is to say, something big, like a ground plane.